# Why junction removal method doesn't work like this?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

This is a question from my textbook's chapter on electrical currents. It has a square circuit as shown in figure 1, where all the wires have identical resistivity.

While solving the circuit the author removed the junction as in figure 2, and said it's all due to symmetry.

I have two questions:

1. What the symmetry has to do with the current.
2. If there is really no current in the junction, why can't it break like I have drawn in figure 3?

[image: diagrams]

Comment: Your pictures are ambiguous: one can draw more than one equivalent circuits placing resistances in various places and doing or not doing some connections. Please instead provide equivalent circuits (this might also let you better understand what's going on).

Comment: This same diagram is in book, however if you you want I can write the whole question when I am on my PC.

Comment: @Ruslan This equivalent circuit and the "connection removal method" is actually one of the general bag of tricks that are employed to solve such circuits and is just one of the ways you can do it. Hence, the circuit produced in the diagram is just what helps in visualizing the symmetry and allows us to compute the resistance in terms of parallel and circuit connections.

Comment: @SatwikPasani I mean that when one can't see the resistances (i.e. rectangles or -VVVV- things), one can assume anything on which wires have equal resistance - e.g. the whole diagonals, or maybe halves, etc. I just haven't seen _such_ diagrams anywhere.

Comment: @Ruslan That's a true concern but by looking at the solution it appears that each half of the diagonal will have resistance equal to one of its side but it is not relevant as to the symmetry in the question which is applicable nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What the symmetry has to do with the current

The symmetry used in the operation is not applied to the current but to the arrangement of the resistors in your particular circuit. The current starting from point 2 will travel along two different direction as 2$\rightarrow$C(centre) and 2$\rightarrow$4. At the centre two currents enter, one from the point 4 and another from the point 2. This circuit has a symmetry about the points 1 and 2, such that whatever the current that passes into the 2$\rightarrow$C will be the same current to move from C$\rightarrow$1 and the same holds for the current from 4 and the current towards 3. This is a consequence of the symmetry about the points 1 and 2 which makes it essential that the current distribution be unaltered even if you rotate the circuit about the perpendicular bisector of line$1\rightarrow 2$. Therefore, at the center the net effect is as if the connection is not valid and can be broken as in figure 2 since there is no "exchange" of current between the two parts into which the junction is split in figure 2, the current from 2 to the center moves independently of the current from 4 towards 1.

> If there is really no current in the junction, why it can't break like
>   I have drawn

There is current in the junction but it is just the division which makes removal of the connection for calculation sake plausible. If you divide it the way you do in figure 3, you are not exploiting the symmetry and hence the divided circuit is not the same as the original circuit with the intact junction. The current of the 2$\rightarrow$C and the C$\rightarrow$1 branches is the same and not 2$\rightarrow$c and C$\rightarrow$4. If the later had been true, figure 3 would have been correct but in this case figure 2 is correct.

Comment: Thanks, is the same ideology applied to all such questions?

Comment: Yes, if you can identify "such" type of questions. Exploiting the symmetry is a bit difficult and you need to identify where such a "connection removal" is applicable. In other cases you can identify places with same potential due to the symmetry and then reduce your question to a simpler circuit.

Comment: Isn't there a different way to solve such questions?

Comment: This particular question cannot be solved(I haven't found an alternate way) by finding same potential regions to reduce your circuit or by exploiting any other symmetry in the diagram. You could do this by say dividing current in a manner dictated by the symmetry but that would be the same as the method we have already pursued. Anyway, You can ALWAYS apply Kirchoff's rules but they are too tedious.